# Combining Auto and *

Tags: wpf, xaml

Lets assume that I have grid with 3 columns:

```
1st column requires minimum height of 100 to display its content
2nd column requires minimum height of 200 to display its content
3rd column requires minimum height of 300 to display its content
```

Total required height is 600. If available space is 900 pixels, then extra 300 pixels should be equally split amongst columns, so the final result is:

```
1st column height = 200
2nd column height = 300
3rd column height = 400
```

if I use * for setting height, then the final result is each column 300 pixels, which is not what I want. Basically I need a combination of auto and *. Can this be done in xaml?

Comment: what about setting Width to "Auto" and setting MinWidth to 100,200, and 300 ?

Comment: column height ? or did you mean width ?

Comment: height, yes. Sorry for the typo

Comment: But you wrote "columns" in your question, you should rephrase it "rows" :)

Comment: Rows, columns, doesnt matter. :) The philosophy is the same for both. I do not know MinWidth, its different for different content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="800"
        Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"
                           MinHeight="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"
                           MinHeight="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"
                           MinHeight="300" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Background="LightBlue"
                    Text="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Background="LightCyan"
                   Text="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                   Background="LightCoral"
                   Text="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You will see that the heights are at least 100, 200, 300, but as soon there is enough place, the extra place will be equally distributed to the rows.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what is the minimum height required to display content. It could be different for different language. This is why I said I need a combination of Auto (which will assign height just enough to display content) and * (to equally distribute free space amongst all columns).

Answer (score 0):

1st col height=2*

2nd col height=3*

3rd col height=4*

Comment: This won't equally distribute the place.